# Howto create docker image tar directly from build step?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration

I want to create a shareable image which can be `docker load`ed into another docker installation directly from `docker build`

e.g.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM my-app/env as builder
COPY /my-app /my-app
RUN /my-app/build.sh

FROM ubuntu:20.04
COPY --from=builder /my-app/build/my-app.exe /bin
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        ***some stuff required at runtime*** \
    && apt-get autoclean \
    && apt-get autoremove \
    && ldconfig
ENTRYPOINT ["my-app.exe"]
CMD ["--help"]
```

Running something like:

```sh
/my-app$ docker build -t my-app/exe .
```

will produce an image which I can use with

```sh
$ docker run my-app/exe
```

If I want to now share this, I need to do:

```sh
$ docker save -o my-app.tar my-app/exe
```

which creates the archive `my-app.tar` which can be shared with another system running the same arch/OS and used by:

```sh
/my-othersystem/my-app$ docker load < my-app.tar
```

And

```sh
$ docker run my-app/exe
```

now works on the other system.

***HOWEVER***

This requires building the image into the build system docker repository then saving the image to a file. I don't plan to run the exeutable on the build system so don't want it taking up space.

You can do:

```sh
/my-app$ DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --output type=tar,dest=out.tar .
```

But this creates a FS, not an image. I want it to be exported as a docker image compatible with `docker load` directly, is this possible?

Comment: Do you have access to a Docker registry, or can you run one yourself?  The more typical setup is to `docker push` the image to a registry once you've built it.  You should only need `docker save` and `docker load` in unusual cases where there's no network connectivity between the build system, the registry, and the target system.

Comment: The target system does not have access to the Internet to pull it from a remote registry. I need to use load in order to get the image on there